# How to calculate ratio using sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, oracle

I have a table like below:

```
ID   Name   Department Gender
1    Crib     MA        MALE
2    Lucy     Bsc       FEMALE
3    Phil     Bcom      MALE
4    Ane      MA        FEMALE
```

I have 1000 row of records like this. I want to find the ratio from column Gender( MALE & FEMALE) of all students.

I need a query to perform this.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? You tagged sql server, mysql and oracle.

Answer (score 17):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8360f/4)

**MySQL 5.5.32 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table1
    (`ID` int, `Name` varchar(4), `Department` varchar(4), `Gender` varchar(6))
;

INSERT INTO table1
    (`ID`, `Name`, `Department`, `Gender`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Crib', 'MA', 'MALE'),
    (2, 'Lucy', 'Bsc', 'FEMALE'),
    (3, 'Phil', 'Bcom', 'MALE'),
    (4, 'Ane', 'MA', 'FEMALE')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT sum(case when `Gender` = 'MALE' then 1 else 0 end)/count(*) as male_ratio,
       sum(case when `Gender` = 'FEMALE' then 1 else 0 end)/count(*) as female_ratio
FROM table1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8360f/4/0)**:

```
| MALE_RATIO | FEMALE_RATIO |
|------------|--------------|
|        0.5 |          0.5 |
```

Comment: If you want to get  decimal points, adjust as follows: ```SELECT CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN `Gender` = 'MALE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FLOAT)/CAST(COUNT(*) AS FLOAT) as male_ratio,```

Comment: In SQL Server, to get decimal points, I needed to multiply by 1.0, like this: ```SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN `Gender` = 'MALE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 1.0 / COUNT(*) as male_ratio,```. Casting to float didn't work for me.

Answer (score 7):

Try something like this

```
select sum(case when gender = 'MALE' then 1 else 0 end) / count(*) * 100 as perc_male,
sum(case when gender = 'FEMALE' then 1 else 0 end) / count(*) * 100 as perc_female
from students
```

Answer (score 1):

This should give you the actual ratio, and should work with little or no modifcation in MySQL and SQL Server.  You may have to modify the cast statement a little - my MySQL is rusty, and I think it may handle that slightly differently.

```
SELECT 
    (CAST((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblName WHERE Gender='MALE') AS FLOAT) / 
     CAST((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblName WHERE Gender='FEMALE') AS FLOAT)) 
    AS ratioMaleFemale;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're pretty close:

```
select (select count(*) 
          from table where gender='MALE' )/count(*)*100 as percentage_male,
       (select count(*) 
          from table where gender='FEMALE' )/count(*)*100 as percentage_female 
from table;
```