# Compute ratio of group sizes using SQL

Tags: sql, vertica

Consider a simple group by query:

```
select foo, count(*)
    from mytable where bar=10 
group by foo
```

This returns a table that has the following form:

```
foo | count
----+------
a   | 100
b   | 200
c   | 300
```

My goal is to get, using a single query the following table:

```
foo | count | ratio
----+-------+-------
a   | 200   | 18.2
b   | 300   | 27.3
c   | 600   | 54.5
```

In practice, I have more possible values of `foo` thus answers like those in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27253333/how-to-calculate-ratio-using-sql-query) are not helpful. Furthermore, not that the ratio is rounded and multiplied by 100.

What is the best practice to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like you want something like this:

```
select foo, count(*),
       count(*) * 100.0 / sum(count(*)) over () as ratio
from mytable
where bar = 10 
group by foo;
```

This does not guarantee that the value adds up to exactly 100% when rounded.  That is a much tricker problem, usually better handled at the application layer.  This does produce the "correct" answer, using floating point numbers.

Comment: Your solution here above is just wrong! I did cut & paste your code (even if not really needed - you just have to read it) and produces wrong results. Did you try to run it?

Comment: That's work completely as expected.
@mauro would you like to explain what you saw wrong here??

Answer (score -1):

Here's a working example that drags its own data along - which you can modify to your individual needs:

```
    SQL>WITH mytable(
    ...>foo , counter
    ...>) AS (
    ...>          SELECT 'a',200
    ...>UNION ALL SELECT 'b',300
    ...>UNION ALL SELECT 'c',600
    ...>)
    ...>SELECT
    ...>  foo
    ...>, counter
    ...>, (counter * 100.0 / SUM(counter) OVER ())::NUMERIC(3,1) AS ratio
    ...>FROM mytable
    ...>;
    foo|counter             |ratio
    a  |                 200| 18.2
    b  |                 300| 27.3
    c  |                 600| 54.5
    select succeeded; 3 rows fetched
```

Happy playing ...
marcothesane

Comment: OP said "In practice, I have more possible values of foo thus answers like those in here are not helpful."